# difftime() between 2 dates that are the same returns 0, is there a way to return 1?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a joined data frame that looks like this:

```
DF <-  structure(list(OpenUser = c(11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 
11111), OpenFirstName = c("Sigal", "Sigal", "Sigal", "Sigal", 
"Sigal", "Sigal"), OpenLastName = c("segal", "segal", "segal", 
"segal", "segal", "segal"), CRMEventStartDate = structure(c(1430524800, 
1430524800, 1435881600, 1435881600, 1425168000, 1425168000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), CustomerID = c(7033, 7033, 7033, 7033, 
9040, 9040), Application = c("Incoming Call", "Incoming Call", 
"Incoming Call", "Incoming Call", "Incoming Call", "Incoming Call"
), CustomerType = c("Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private"), CampaignStrategyID = c(121212, 512345, 
121212, 512345, 512345, 516345), ResponseDate = structure(c(1435881600, 
1430524800, 1435881600, 1430524800, 1425168000, 1430870400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ResponseCode = c(3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1), 
    days = c(62, 0, 0, -62, 0, 66)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I have two problems with that data frame:

1) difftime between two dates that are the same returns 0, i need it to return 1.

2) this is a joined data frame. somehow my join returned undesired rows where you can see that the `"CRMEventstartdate"` comes **after** the `"ResponseDate"` which is impossible. The date of response should **always** be the same day or after, **NOT** before. why is that happening and how do i prevent it?

the two data frames that were joined are:

```
Calls <- structure(list(OpenUser = c(11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 
11111), OpenFirstName = c("Sigal", "Sigal", "Sigal", "Sigal", 
"Sigal", "Sigal"), OpenLastName = c("segal", "segal", "segal", 
"segal", "segal", "segal"), CRMEventStartDate = structure(c(1430524800, 
1435881600, 1425168000, 1438473600, 1417478400, 1435881600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), CustomerID = c(7033, 7033, 9040, 17472, 
35099, 39778), Application = c("Incoming Call", "Incoming Call", 
"Incoming Call", "Incoming Call", "Incoming Call", "Incoming Call"
), CustomerType = c("Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

AND

```
Response <- structure(list(CampaignStrategyID = c(512345, 512345, 512345, 
121212, 512345, 121212), CustomerID = c(836, 1070, 1390, 2970, 
3479, 3646), ResponseDate = structure(c(1441065600, 1441065600, 
1431129600, 1435881600, 1420502400, 1417392000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ResponseCode = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code used to join and calculate the difftime was:

```
DF <- inner_join(Calls,Response,by="CustomerID") %>% 
   mutate(days=as.numeric(difftime(ResponseDate,CRMEventStartDate,units = "days")))
```

Comment: As to your "undesired rows", I would suggest looking at the data. Find a customer ID with the problem you see, and look at the raw data in both. It sounds like a dirty data problem, not a join problem. If you find something where it looks like the `inner_join` is giving an incorrect result, please share a sample of data that shows the problem. The samples you share have no matching customer IDs, making them not very illustrative...

Comment: Though we can see that `Response` has duplicated customer IDs. If `Calls` also has repeated customer IDs, you probably want additional logic to figure out *which* response for customer X goes with which call. Maybe it's always the ResponseDate closest to but greater than or equal to the CRMEventStartDate, but maybe not. Maybe I call you today, and again tomorrow, and then the next day get a response to my second call, but it takes a week to get a response to my first call. We can't know if that's possible in your data...

Answer (score 0):

Pick whichever you like of these. They will change 0s to 1s.

```
mutate(days = pmin(as.numeric(difftime(ResponseDate,CRMEventStartDate,units = "days")), 1))

mutate(days = as.numeric(difftime(ResponseDate,CRMEventStartDate,units = "days")),
       days = ifelse(days == 0, 1, days))
```